# Avoiding extra tax - UK

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom

For the past 10 years I have been earning from an employed job, with all taxes paid before I receive my salary. (Around £60k)

I have recently started to do extra work for which I receive the payment into my bank account, but this is untaxed and I would have to eventually declare it. This extra income would be a maximum of £6k a year. Currently they are depositing this in a personal account of mine.

I would like to avoid paying as little tax as possible on this extra income.

I am above the threshold for marriage allowance.

What are some suggestions?

I have had a friend suggest getting the pay into a joint account with my wife and declaring it as her income as she does not earn. But then I am registered with the company paying me.

Comment: Do you have children that you are receiving child benefit for?

Comment: Please clarify the statement "I would like to avoid paying as little tax as possible on this extra income."

Comment: "_and declaring it as her income_" sounds like your friend is advising fraud.

Answer (score -1):

You can start a limited company, which is very cheap. Your company sends bills for £6,000. You also join the VAT flat rate scheme if you are billing companies, not if you billing private citizens.

You pay no salary. So £6,000 profit, and you pay 19% of that as corporation tax. You add 20% VAT to each bill, which costs companies nothing. Of those 20%, 17.4% go to HMRC so you keep 2.4% - that’s £144 free money.

From the money, you pay a £2000 tax free dividend every year (however, the tax free amount will go down soon). The rest stays in the company, until you retire, or lose your job and need money, and then you pay it out as dividends. Or you pay it into a pension fund.

Comment: Isn't the 17% that goes to HMRC of the VAT-inclusive amount, that is 120% of the original invoice? Within pennies, you'd be left with the original amount?

Comment: No, you pay 14.5% of the amount including VAT. For a £100 bill, you get £120 including VAT, you pay 14.5% = £17.40 to HMRC, you keep £2.60. 14.5% of 120% is 17.4% of 100%.